# Checking user entered details against response JSON

Tags: json, angular, spring

I am trying to setup an Angular app which authenticates users against a back-end server. I am able to get the list of users from server as a JSON in my Angular list. How can I now validate this against user input fields.

Since I have already got the list of users I just have to validate the user entered inputs against that. But for some reason it doesn't work.

Code to get list of all users

```
getListofUsers() {
return this.httpClient.get(this.userListURL);
}

this.authService.getListofUsers()
    .subscribe(resp => {
      console.log(resp, "res");
      this.data = resp
    },
      error => {
        console.log(error, "error");
      })
```

Data variable contains the response JSON.

I want to validate user input fields against this JSON response

```
 this.authService.authenticateUser({
  userId: this.userId.value,
  userPassword: this.userPassword.value},this.data)
```

If userID and password are present in response JSON then the user should be routed to next screen.

```
  this.router.routeToDashboard();
```

Comment: You can simply check for existence of your userid and password in response array.

Comment: Like CodeReady mentions, Inside the authenticateUser method, you'll have to do some sort of mapping and comparison between the userId and userPassword and the data inside of ```this.data```.